# Best location for sqlite db file on mac OSX

Tags: database, macos, sqlite, delphi, deployment

I am deploying a Delphi Firemonkey app on Mac OSX and being new to Mac programming I am wondering where I should install the sqlite database file.

Under Windows I usually put it in the application installation directory but this isn't appropriate on a Mac (I think!).

There will not be a need for multi-user access to the db file

I have currently placed it in /Library/Application Support/Myapp/Myapp.db but wonder if there is a better (or official) place to put it.

Comment: You might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/q/8159485/1026660

Comment: On a side note, the application installation directory is *not* the place to put any writable data. That directory is read-only, has been since Windows Vista. If you are writing to this directory, then your design is flawed, and you're taking a back door. Take a look at `TPath.GetHomePath` as found in `System.IOUtils`.

Comment: Yes I realise that.   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you take a look at the [guidelines from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/AppRuntime/AppRuntime.html).

You can use '/Library/Application Support/Myapp/Myapp.db' if the database does not contain user specific data. Otherwise use '~/Library/Application Support/Myapp/Myapp.db'.

Please don't hard code those folders, but use `NSFileManager.URLForDirectory` for retrieving them.